# How to use htaccess to redirect all but one subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-alias

It's been a while since I've messed with .htaccess and I can't seem to get this quite right. I have a site, say example.com, where I want example.com/* to redirect to example.com/collector.html *except* for URLs under the subdirectory example.com/special, which I want to continue working.

For example:

- example.com/page.html should redirect to example.com/collector.html
- example.com/foo/bar should redirect to example.com/collector.html
- example.com/special/page.html should not redirect

I would have thought that something like

```
RedirectMatch 302 ^/[^(special)]/.* /collector.html
RedirectMatch 302 ^/[^(collector.html)/]* /collector.html
```

would do the trick, but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this? (needs mod_rewrite)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule !^(special(/.*)?|collector\.html)$ collector.html [R,L]
```

Comment: I thought about this but i think he wants to explicitly redirect the user with a 302 code...

Comment: That's what the [R] flag does

Comment: Had to make a small modification, changed "special/" to "special/?" so that "example.com/special" doesn't redirect, but other than that this worked, thanks!

Comment: @Tyler: You might want to make the regex part "!^(special(/.*)?|collector\.html)$" then, because your version will not redirect on URLs like "http://example.com/specialpage.html". I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me on Apache 2.2.13 where I recreated the directory structure you described.

```
RedirectMatch 302 /(?!special)  http://www.example.com/collector.html
```

The pattern in the brackets is saying do NOT match if the URI contains the string 'special'.

Also mod rewrite is not always available and in this case is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RedirectMatch 302 /\/[^(special)]\/.+/ /collector.html 
RedirectMatch 302 /\/[^(collector\.html)]/ /collector.html
```

Comment: This works to get all subdirectories to go to the collector, but doesn't work to redirect files in the root, e.g. example.com/page.html

Comment: What's happen ? Does the page is retrieved correctly without any redirect ?

Comment: Try this on the same line : RedirectMatch 302 /\/[^(special\/)|(collector\.html)].*/ /collector.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe...?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(?!special) collector.html [R,NC]
```